# (0,_reactNavigation.DrawerNavigator) is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am newbie in React Native.
I wanna create simple drawer navigation, but I get error here.

I have done installed the react navigation.
Here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
StatusBar ,
TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';

import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Screen1 from './Screen1';
import Screen2 from './Screen2'; 

const Drawer= DrawerNavigator({
    Home:{
        screen: Screen1
    },
    Home2:{
        screen: Screen2
    }
})

export default Drawer
```

I expect the screen consist drawer navigator.

but I get error:

> (0,_reactNavigation.DrawerNavigator) is not a function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not `DrawerNavigation` but `createDrawerNavigation`.

If you are using `react-navigation` > V.4, these function has been moved to another repo. In you case, `createDrawerNavigator` is located in `react-navigation-drawer` so you need to install it (by using `npm` or `yarn`).

After that when you import it you just need to do:

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
```

and then just use it as you are already doing.

If you are using `react-navigation` version 2 or 3 it's

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

without having to install any other library.

`DrawerNavigator` is used in `react-navigation` version 1.

Comment: I think it's ```createDrawerNavigator``` not ```createDrawerNavigation``` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/4.x/drawer-navigator.html

Comment: Yes, 100%. My bad!

Comment: as i have tried the above code but i am getting a error like 
' Failed building JavaScript bundle.
While trying to resolve module `react-navigation-drawer` from file `/home/ankit/Desktop/intren⁄resume/quizzi/screen/mainscreen.js`, the package `/home/ankit/Desktop/intren⁄resume/quizzi/node_modules/react-navigation-drawer/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/home/ankit/Desktop/intren⁄resume/quizzi/node_modules/react-navigation-drawer/lib/module/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:'

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps you need to follow for setup the react navigation:

1) Import drawer navigator in your root file:

```
import { createSwitchNavigator, createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
```

2) Then create the drawer navigation:

```
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home
    },
    MyOrders: {
        screen: MyOrders
    },
});
```

3) Call your drawer navigator in stack navigator or switch navigator mine is Switch navigator:

```
const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    InitialScreen: {
        screen: InitialScreen
    },
    Login: {
        screen: Login
    },
    Forgot: {
        screen: Forgot
    },
    SuccessMessage: {
        screen: SuccessMessage
    },
    Drawer: AppDrawerNavigator,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'InitialScreen',
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    gesturesEnabled: false,
    header:null
  }
});
```

4) Import anywhere:

```
import { DrawerActions } from "react-navigation";
```

and call it with menu icon like

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
```

This will open your drawer navigator let me know if anything you need to help.